# Validating fields based on variables that may change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, activerecord

I'm trying to validate a date of birth field that has to be in a certain range:

```
validates :year_of_birth, :inclusion => { :in => 1900..Date.today.year - 5 }
```

Although for this case it wouldn't pose such a big problem, I realized that this is only valid in development where models are reloaded every time and thus the current year is calculated again.

When in production, how would I avoid that, say, at the turn of the year, the right end of the range remains the same as it was the year before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cases like these, I suggest you go for a custom validation.

```
validate :validates_year_of_birth

def validates_year_of_birth
  five_years_ago = 5.years.ago.year
  if year_or_birth && (year_of_birth < 1990 || year_of_birth > five_years_ago)
    errors.add :year_of_birth, "should be between 1990 and #{five_years_ago}"
  end
end
```

or you can pass the validation in a proc

```
validates :year_of_birth, :inclusion => { :in => proc { 1900..5.years.ago.year } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I opted for the proc way because it seemed a much more slim solution for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for letting me know about the existence of custom validators!